# Problem registering custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here.

I'm trying to register a custom taxonomy called 'location' for my custom post type 'member'. But in the WP backend it's still coming up as 'category'.

???

```
add_action('init', 'gws_lt_register_cpts');

//register custom post types
function gws_lt_register_cpts() {
    //member labels
 $gws_lt_mem_labels = array(
    'name' => 'Members',
    'singular_name' => 'Member',
    'add_new' => 'Add New Member',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Member',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Member',
    'new_item' => 'New Member',
    'all_items' => 'All Members',
    'view_item' => 'View Member',
    'view_items' => 'View Members',
    'search_items' => 'Search Members',
    'not_found' =>  'No Members found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Members found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'archives' => 'Member Archives',
    'attributes' => 'Member Attributes',
    'insert_into_item' => 'Insert into Member',
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this Member'
);

    //member arguments
 $gws_lt_mem_args = array(
    'labels' => $gws_lt_mem_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('locations')
);

    //register members
 register_post_type('member', $gws_lt_mem_args);

}

//register taxonomies
add_action('init','gws_lt_reg_tax');

function gws_lt_reg_tax() {

$loc_args = array('name'=> 'Locations', 'singular_name'=>'Location', 'menu_name'=>'Locations', 'hierarchical' => true);

register_taxonomy('locations', array('member'), $loc_args);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't passed the labels to `register_taxonomy()` correctly. That function works the same as `register_post_type()`, and you need to pass the labels the same way: as part of a `'labels'` array in the arguments.

Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) for the full list of accepted labels, but essentially, you need to organise the arguments this way:

```
$loc_args = array( 
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels'       => array(
        'name'          => 'Locations', 
        'singular_name' => 'Location', 
    ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'locations', array( 'member' ), $loc_args );
```

That's only 2 of the labels though. You will need to provide the [full list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy_labels/) so that "Category" does not appear anywhere.